# Operator == doesn't work in C

Tags: c, if-statement, gcc, operators

I'm getting a weird error while writing my program in C.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "defs.h"
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
 int boardSize = atoi(argv[2]);

 int generations = atoi(argv[4]);

int gamesort = atoi(argv[1]);
printf("2 is %d 1 is %d 4 is %d name of file is %s \n",boardSize,gamesort,generations,argv[3]);

    if (1==1)
    {
    printf("yes");
        ZeroPlayersGame(boardSize, generations,argv[3]);
    }
    else//(gamesort==2)
    {
        TwoPlayersGame(boardSize, generations,argv[3]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the error im getting from the Terminal:

```
ise@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ make

gcc -c main.c defs.c gameIO.c zeroPlayer.c twoPlayer.c

gcc gameIO.o defs.o zeroPlayer.o main.o twoPlayer.o -o prog

ise@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ./prog 1 2 "l.txt" 3

2 is 2 1 is 1 4 is 3 name of file is l.txt 

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Very strange, as you can see my program dosen't enter my first "if",
but you can see it prints the line before the if statment.

thanks for any help!

Comment: how do you know? you did not flush.

Comment: there is a printf inside my if that dosent get print.

Comment: To make sure the output gets flushed ot the terminal, try adding a newline: `printf("yes\n");`.  You are getting the crash in the call to `ZeroPlayersGame()`

Comment: and if you remove the functions call (`ZeroPlayersGame` and `TwoPlayersGame`) lines? are you still getting segmentation fault?

Comment: @YardenRotem great! good luck ;-)

Comment: Further to @MichaelBurr's comment, safer still is to use `stderr` for trace messages, since `stderr` is unbuffered:  `fprintf(stderr, "yes\n");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is not related to your question title "Operator == doesn't work in C". As seen in your output, printf works well and there may be possibly a problem in functions "ZeroPlayersGame" and "TwoPlayersGame". If you gave us more information about these two functions, solving the problem would be easier. 
Also, using "1==1" in logical statement is so weird. Why don't you eliminate it and write your statement just after the printf statement. Because "1==1" is always true.

Comment: thank you, as i wrote before, vereything worked out.